# Spring MVC Security Auto Login Use Cas Server JASIG

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, single-sign-on, cas

I have mutiple site..
example :

```
http://example1.com 
http://example2.com
```

and i have cas server `https://example.com`,if i already login in cas server why in my other site not automatic login,,must be have some action like go to url `http://example2.com/login` ,i dont want user do some action,,if i already login in my cas server after that i go to other site,,that site can automatic login.

this my spring security configuration..

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="casAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="casSingleSignOutFilter" class="org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter"/>

<beans:bean id="casAuthEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <beans:property name="loginUrl" value="https://example.com/cas/" />
    <beans:property name="serviceProperties" ref="casService" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="casService"
    class="org.springframework.security.cas.ServiceProperties">
    <beans:property name="service"
        value="http://example2.com/auth_check"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="casAuthenticationFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" /> <!-- Required -->
    <beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/auth_check" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- Auth Provider -->
<beans:bean id="casAuthenticationProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="ticketValidator" ref="casTicketValidator" /><!-- Required -->
    <!-- <beans:property name="ticketValidator" ref="samlTicketValidator"/> -->
    <beans:property name="serviceProperties" ref="casService" /> <!-- Required -->
    <beans:property name="key" value="example2-cas" /> <!-- Required -->
    <beans:property name="authenticationUserDetailsService"
        ref="authenticationUserDetailsService" />
</beans:bean>
```

any suggestion would be help to me.

Answer (score 0):

Spring security will only force authentication when the resource is protected. If you want CAS to authenticate your users immediately, you'll want to change your spring security role mappings to not allow the ANONYMOUS user to have access to your index page, etc.